# Is there a C++ version of ungetc?

Tags: c++, io, iostream, undo, ungetc

Is there a C++ version of ungetc?

That is, can I put a character back onto an istream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. [istream::putback](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/putback/) is the same as ungetc [except if using unget()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769416/difference-between-putback-and-unget/6769623#6769623):

> You can't lie with unget(). It "ungets" the last-read character. You
>   can lie with putback(c). You can "putback" some character other than
>   the last-read character. Sometimes putting back a character other than
>   the last-read character can be useful.
>
> Also, if the underlying read buffer really does have buffering
>   capability, you can "putback" more than one character. I think
>   ungetc() is limited to one character.

Comment: `istream::unget` is not `ungetc`. You can lie with `ungetc`.

Comment: @Martinho: That's just `putback` instead

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning the `peek` method, because most wants for `unget` are just the second step of implementing "I want to peek the next character".

Answer (score 2):

You can put a character back with the [istream::putback](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/putback/) function. You can even put a different character if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/putback/